# Filtering a numpy.dstack

Tags: python, numpy, filter, stack

I have a dstack like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array((1,2,6))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
c = np.array((8,3,0))
stack = np.dstack((a,b,c))
print(stack)
#[[[1 2 8]
  #[2 3 3]
  #[6 4 0]]]
```

and I want to filter out the lists where the 2 element is less then 1.

Something like this:

```
new_list = []

for i in stack:
    for d in i[:,2]:
        if d>=1:
            new_list.append(d)
print(new_list) # [8,3]
```

Doing this only the 2 element is added, but I would like to have all the row, like this:

```
#[[[1 2 8]
  #[2 3 3]]]
```

And if I `append(i)` the result is not the desired one either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can do it with slicing

```
print(stack[stack[:,2] >= 1])
```

Output

```
[[1 2 8]
 [2 3 3]]
```

If you need it as

```
[[[1 2 8]]
 [[2 3 3]]]
```

you can `reshape` the result

```
stack = stack[stack[:,2] >= 1]
shape = stack.shape
print(stack[stack[:,2] >= 1].reshape((shape[0], 1, shape[1])))
```